# CQL : ConfigurationException: Keyspace refined_zone_uat doesn't exist

Tags: cassandra

```
create table refined_zone_uat.unprocessed_contact_records_fraudring (
trade_acc_number text,
contact_sf_id text ,
email text ,
ip_address text ,
mobile_phone text ,
first_name text ,
last_name text ,
acc_sf_id text ,
device_id text,
street text ,
post_code text ,
added_date timestamp ,
org_code text,
PRIMARY KEY (contact_sf_id, added_date)
);
```

SHowing error : "`ConfigurationException: Keyspace refined_zone_uat doesn't exist`"

But Keyspace : "`unprocessed_contact_records_fraudring`" is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the create table syntax Faisal

https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateTable.html

Looks like keyspace and table in your statement is reversed. It should be

```
CREATE TABLE {keyspace}.{table_name} (....);
```